# FactoMineR: detecting dimensions with noises

Tags: r, clustering, pca

I have some categorical datasets and was considering to do MCA using FactoMineR. Is there a way to detect dimensions with noises in FactoMineR? Considering to do a cluster analysis afterwards so it would be better if I leave those dimensions from the analysis.